# Crashes when copying SQLite db from bundle to documents and then querying

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, sqlite, grand-central-dispatch, exc-bad-access

This makes absolutely no sense (to me).

SQLite will throw `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors randomly (on the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` line in the Db class) when querying when I copy the database from the bundle to the documents folder in a background thread. But, if I don't perform it in a background thread then no crashes ever occur.

The reason I want to perform the operation in a thread is that it is quite large (~150MB).

My `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` looks like this - the working script is commented out below the GCD thread:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    dispatch_queue_t setupDb = dispatch_queue_create("setupDb", NULL);
    dispatch_async(setupDb, ^{
        [Db setup];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [Db connect];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"databaseReady" object:nil];
        });
    });

//  If using this code, though, it works perfectly fine
//  [Db setup];
//  [Db connect];
//  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"databaseReady" object:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

The database class looks like (`_statement` is defined in the `.h`):

```
@implementation Db

static sqlite3  * _db;
static NSString * _dbPath;

+ (BOOL)setup {
    NSString      * sqlBundlePath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSString      * documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString      * sqlDocumentPath = [[documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"];
    NSFileManager * fileManager     = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Make sure we don't already have the database in our documents, we don't want to overwrite!
    if (! [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sqlDocumentPath]) {
        BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sqlBundlePath toPath:sqlDocumentPath error:nil];

        if (! success) {
            NSLog(@"Error copying database");
            return NO;
        }
    }

    _dbPath = sqlDocumentPath;

    return YES;
}

+ (BOOL)connect {
    sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);
    sqlite3_open([_dbPath UTF8String], &_db);

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)prepare:(const char *)sql {
    if (! sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, sql, -1, &_statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Error whilst preparing query: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
        sqlite3_finalize(_statement);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)step {
    if (sqlite3_step(_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)finalise {
    sqlite3_finalize(_statement);
}

@end
```

Comment: FYI - your `prepare:` method has several problems. The `if` statement should be: `if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, sql, -1, &_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)`. And there is no reason to call `sqlite3_finalize` if the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails.

Comment: Also, your `Db` class is not designed in a way you want. What happens if your app needs change and you wish to support more than one database? And why do you have both class and instance methods accessing the same static variables? And what if you need more than one query at a time?

Comment: You did not show/tell us when and where you actuall call `[Db prepare: xxx]`. The most plausible explanation for the problem you describe would be that you call prepare while the asynchronous setup+connection are not yet finished.

Comment: Are you calling this code from a single background thread? Or do you have multiple threads calling the same series of methods at the same time? Or, more to the point, do you possibly have multiple statements open at the same time? This code is not threadsafe.

Comment: @Rob Multiple threads would be running queries at the same time - how could I make it thread safe?

Comment: @Rob Yes, I have omitted the binding statements for brevity :) The way the class works is that you can instantiate it multiple times when you want to run queries by just calling `Db * db = [[Db alloc] init]` and then `[db prepare:"..."]`, the `_db` will be available and the `_statement` would be unused and free. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Rob Yes, that is correct. Each time I create a `Db` instance it only ever runs one query at a time. There will, however, be multiple threads running queries all the time (some running thousands of queries per minute). This app has been running, database wise, crash-free for ~6 months (reported by Crashlytics). It's only when moving the database copying into a background thread that crashes occur.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100081/discussion-between-rob-and-cjhill).